# How to make a .net application which is also a zip file?

Tags: .net, zip

I know this can be done. Can you show how to create a .net exe which also can be opened as a zip file with any zip file browser?

Comment: What does that even mean?  You mean a self-extracting ZIP? http://kb.winzip.com/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=179

Comment: Why would someone want to do that? Futhermore I'd doubt that this is possible. Maybe you're mistaken an self extracing ZIP archive with an acutal application?

Comment: It's possible. The PE file format uses a header. THe ZIP format uses a suffix. One file can have both.

Comment: I guess the suffix block would be "end of central dir signature 0x06054b50"

Comment: and to be clear, a self-extracting zip *is* an actual application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you meant a self extracting file, but I found your question interesting because there is a way to make a file that can be opened both as a jpeg and as zip like this:

(in Windows command line)

```
copy /b image.jpg + zipped_file.zip combo.jpg
```

Comment: No your credit card info will be protected by NTFS Alternate Data Streams (support.microsoft.com/kb/105763).

But seriously, the copy trick seems to be what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

May be better than that you can use [.NETZ Tool](http://madebits.com/netz/index.php)

```
 netz -s app.exe lib1.dll lib2.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to create a self executing ZIP file. Have [a look at this](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=179). At least that is assuming what you mean, if not please provide further details...

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) makes self-extracting zip archives, and you can include a command to run on extract.

see also: [Creating a Zip Extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578823/creating-a-zip-extractor)